# Jersey with Spring Tomcat doesnot start after adding spring web 4.3.5 jar

Tags: spring, jersey, tomcat8

I am trying to create a REST service using Jersey and spring.(eclipse IDE with Tomcat 8.0 server)
I have added the "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" as the listener in web.xml.

```
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I added Spring-Web 4.3.5 jar in the classpath of the Tomcat server in eclipse, but after adding this TomCat does not start.

```
 Mar 28, 2017 12:52:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1015)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1631)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
```

how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved:

Solution: Removed the jar from Server Class path
Instead added the jar as part of the Deployment assembly section  for the project.

How to add a jar to the Deployment assembly:
Right click - properties- Deployment assembly- add the jar.